# Problems operating on my computer

Tags: windows-7, laptop

This problem really startles me. It feels like my laptop refuses to take certain commands or  accepts them and then returns to the previous page/folder/... Here are some examples of what I mean:

I want to check what programs are installed on my computer, so I go to "Control Panel". Then I click on programs. I briefly (just a tenth of a second) see the next page and then it returns me to the control panel home screen. I then cannot click the programs option for a few seconds anymore. Getting the "explorer link" (the text in the explorer breadcrumb box) from another computer and pasting that gives the same problem.

Another example is in IE, I try to google something. When I press enter, the text disappears and I'm back on the google homescreen. When clicking outside the searchbox (on a link in the search results or ust on the white background) I'm forwarded to the homepage again. Only typing in the url in the address bar takes me to another page (and then it multiplies by creating new tabs endlessly).

A third example is I'm trying to open a program to check some things on the computer. I unzipped the program to a folder, but clicking that folder only gives me a busy indicator for a brief second and then shows the parent folder again.

Furthermore, I cannot open the eventviewer in the applications tab. So I enter eventvwr in the run box, and am taken to the eventviewer. When I click on "application", the screen returns to logbooks (first option in the tree).

Finally, I also noticed that when I try to open an attachment in outlook, the focus should change to the attachment, but it hops back to "message".

I'm working on a Win 7 Pro SP1 (32-bit) Hp computer. Restarting the computer helps for a while, but it starts again later (time till problems after reboot can vary).

Does anyone recognize this problem and can guide me towards a solution? I don't have full time access to the computer so it's not possible to just go ahead and check some minor things. Any suggestions are welcome though.

**Edit**
Everything (Windows, Virus Scan,..) are up to date. No virusses are found.
We've also took care of the msconfig, there's nothing excessive running there.

**Edit 2**
Working with a keylogger didn't give me the results I'd expected. There're no hidden keycommands that are being sent, still the problems occur. The problem in troubleshooting this is that it takes a variable amount of time after a reboot before the problem occurs. Any more advice on troubleshooting would be great.

Comment: Your desciption sounds most like a prank (malware) or a stuck key, but i do not know what one key would do all these actions arrow up?. is it Hp desktop or laptop? Your going to want to boot into safe mode, and see if it occurs in it. They also have KeyInfo programs which show what keys are pressed, that helped me find a stuck key one time.

Comment: I've been thinking the same, maybe backspace (return page/folder) but it's hard to explain why in eventviewer it focusses back on the top tree option. The device is a desktop, but aside from keyboards I don't know why that should matter.

Comment: @Psycogeek: Also, a stuck key would mean I get the problem after a reboot, which isn't the case. It works fine after a reboot for a while.

Comment: Have you run a virus check? I would also consider looking at Task Scheduler or the running services, as well as MSCONFIG to ensure nothing is starting which shouldn't be.

Comment: Right, I was asking because of the keyboard. Also if it is wireless keyboard, it could be even more suspect. KeyPresses software can usually show when other stuff is sending the system a key press, I suppose depending on how it is hooked.

Comment: @DaveRook: updates my question, no virusses.

Comment: Cool, do look through the task scheduler/services and start up in the MSCONFIG. It sounds like a program is running after a short delay...

Comment: Do you use any AHK or key mapping? Psycogeek's comments made me think, instead of the issue being a stuck key, it could be a key combination, such as alt + left cursor

Comment: The computer is used by a basic user (practically mouse only). No tools are installed, shortcuts are not used.

Comment: Did you try a new keyboard?

Comment: @DaveRook: opposed to what I stated earlier, it's a notebook (it's not physically present here), so it's not that easy to just change keyboards.

Comment: OK - well, I think you need to find the time, when you can, to try a different keyboard. And your OP doesn't state it's a laptop, it says "computer" (and people shouldn't have to read comments to understand the full question, you should probably update your post to explain this).

Comment: @DaveRook: taking over the computer remotely gives the same problem. I don't think phyical keyboard can give that problem.

Comment: Good idea about the RDP - did you try KeyInfo programs as per Psycogeek's suggestion?

Comment: @DaveRook: I have no experience with any of those tools. If you could recommend a good and reliable tool I could check it out.

Comment: I can't recommend any, but give them a go as it sounds like the machine is constantly spamming a key combination. I really would try safe mode as well...

Comment: As the update suggestsin the question, Keylogger didn't notice anything strange. I'm out of ideas...